# Try to replace <video> with <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `<video>` in View

Here is code

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
        <video id="preview" controls style="border: 1px solid rgb(15, 158, 238); height: 280px; width: 300px;" muted="muted" ;></video>
    </p>
```

and `<div>`

here is code

```
<div id="container" style="padding:1em 2em; width: 350px; text-align: center;margin-left: 100px;margin-top: 50px;"></div>
```

I try to replace video with div like this

```
$('#next').click(function () {
    $('#container').replaceWith($('#preview'));
```

it replaces, but  like hidden

why so?

**UPDATE**

Here is how it likes when I open View

[image]

I click button `Запись` and record video

Here is screen

[image]

I click button `Остановить` and in  I will see recorded video

[image]

When I click `Далее` button it needs to be replaced with

But I see this
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _"but like hidden"_?

Comment: I will update question now@evolutionxbox

Comment: shoudnt be `$("#preview"). replaceWith($("#container"))`?

Comment: My coworkers will wonder why I look at these pictures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this code**

```js
$('#next').click(function () {
    $('#preview').replaceWith($('#container'));
})
```

```css
div#next {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#428bca 0,#3071a9 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #2d6ca2;
    width: 51px;
    height: 21px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="text-align: center;">
        <video id="preview" controls style="border: 1px solid rgb(15, 158, 238); height: 280px; width: 300px;" muted="muted" ;></video>
    </p>
    <div id="next">
    next
    </div>
    
    <div id="container" style="width: 350px; text-align: center;margin-left: 100px;border: 1px solid rgb(15, 158, 238); height: 280px; width: 300px;">div</div>
```

Comment: But next is button